# Visual Studio 2015 slow

Tags: windows, performance, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Hi I just did a new installation of windows 10 and installed visual studio 2015 ultimate.

What I immediately noticed is that visuals studio 2015 is extremely slow for any action I take it has a 1-2 second delay.

Opening a javascript file, writting some code, trying to open source control they all behave the same way.I have installed Web Essentials and Web Compiler on it addons that I have been using frequently in visual studio 2013.

I know my question is vague but I can not seem to find what the source of the problem might be.I looked online and could not find anything o help.

Does anyone now how I could improve the performance of it?

Comment: What's eating the CPU cycles?

Comment: I doubt it will help in this case, but you could try repairing/reinstalling VS.

Comment: Process Monitor from SysInternals FTW.

Comment: That is the Weird part the CPU is not going more then 10%. The memory is a bit high 45-55% I have 8gb ram.I think this might be related to Windows 10 my pc most of the time in windows 8 did not passe 40% and the HDD is at around 5%

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 is this year's disappointment. I thought performance was one of the main issues to resolve..? Try open nuget package manager on a slow network, that freezes everything.

Comment: Ditto @Thomas reply, I am very displeased with VS2015, I've uncovered numerous issues, latest is working with JSON files and doing a lot of Find\Replace's. Microsoft needs to put the brakes on and do some QA.

Comment: Do you have a phone connected by any chance?

Comment: Also, try [disabling CodeLens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457796/how-to-turn-off-codelens-references), that can help improve performance in some situations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 is very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553560/visual-studio-2015-is-very-slow)

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall **Node.js** from **Programes and Features** in the control panel. in addition see the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/31655079/4446346

Comment: Why uninstalling Node.js should improve Visual Studio performance?

Comment: because when i've installed visual studio 2015 on my computer it was very slow and after uninstalling the Node.js add-on things got a lot faster, also you can look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/31553823

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have "maximum battery life" option on the power options.

I made the horrible mistake of enabling that. CPU never went above 5%, and the system was crawling so slow I was sure the computer kicked the bucket. Took me 2 days to realize it was the power options.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in the first week after I had installed windows 10 (clean install not upgrade) and now it works much better. I think that your problem is because of Windows 10, it was not completely polished when it was released but due to the automatic updates, somehow, Microsoft addressed some problems.

Also, do you mean Visual Studio Professional, Enterprise or even Community, no? because there is no Ultimate edition of Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1):

had similar on vs startup;

To resolve my start issue:
I have removed extensions from vs2012 for phones;

repair vs2015 same…
uninstall vs2015 (hang not all removed)

then use:

https://github.com/tsasioglu/Total-Uninstaller

remove all that was possible with vs2015 and vs2013, etc

install vs again error: lookup logs, inet, etc and found vc redist 2015
reinstall and repair vc_redist.x64.exe and vc_redist.x86.exe

installed vs2015 again now no startup issues;
(vsHub can be unisnstalled and connected servis can be disabled…)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same things as you described. My VS15 was really slow. What the magic trick for me was, was updating my GPU drivers. I can't believe how much faster my VS15 is now. Hopefully it will work as great as it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

On wich type of project are you developping ?
If its something like UWP, you may have awful performance issue in VS2015, see my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36429359/1417492

**TL;DR**: You may try to add a new project in your solution that is not related to UWP or WP8.1 (in my case, something like a Xamarin Android) and set it as "Starting Project". See then if you have still performance issue.

For me it was a huge change, however, i cannot tell you if your slow VS2015 is related to the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a bunch of performance improvements released with the Update 2 of VS 2015. I would suggest you to download the Update 2 and try. I have been using it for over a month now & have seen a superlative performance when compared to the initial release.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx#perfrel