# UWP app runs slow in release mode when deployed on Windows 10 Mobile device through store

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, uap

I am facing a strange issue. I have a UWP app published in store. When I deploy this app to my Lumia 930 through the store, it runs very slowly. However, the same app when I deploy to the same device in debug mode from VS 2015, it works fast. To be specific, I am relying on heaving caching in a Sqlite database for displaying the results, plus I also have lot of List processing done in my logic. In debug mode, one specific page with particular set of data takes around 3 seconds to load and show the results. The same page with same data takes 8-9 seconds when running on the same device but downloaded from the store.

Any idea, what I am doing wrong, or is there something which I am missing. The particular app in question is: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/series-tracker/9nblggh3slj9

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What happens when you deploy to your device in release mode - it might have the same slowdown - guessing it might be when in .NET Native mode there's a performance hit on something or it's a call to a method that is more forgiving in debug mode, might be able to use performance monitor to check for issues - but just a guess without any code

Comment: Like @RoguePlanetoid said try it in release mode and also try enabling and disabling "Compile with .NET Native" which can be done under Properties -> Build

Comment: install the app FieldMedic (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/field-medic/9wzdncrfjb82), select Perf_DotNetRT under advanced and click start. Now run your app for 1-2 minutes, switch back to FieldMedic and stop logging. Connect the phone to the PC (USB), copy the ETL file from documents/FieldMedic/reports to your PC and analyte it with WPA (like CPU usage: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis)

Comment: have you captured the trace? Do you see a high cpu usage? were you able to analyze the ETL?

Comment: Hi, not yet. I did try deploying the app in release mode to device, and it is slow. I have collected the stats using Field Meic, and will analyse them tonight.

Comment: I analysed the ETL file, and CPU usage is extremely high. I tested it 3-4 times on same device in release mode with and without Native Toolkit Chaining, and without Native, it is fast. So I can conclude that the issue is with .NET Native Toolkit Chaining. I decided to release my app without Native build, but WACK fails the test. Anyone has noticed an issue with performance when Native build is enabled?

Comment: I found this other thread where people are also complaining about slow performance when Native chaining is enabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855352/why-is-uwp-10-development-so-slow and https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2040265/uwp-layout-performance-and-compilation-to-net-native-chain

Comment: ok, good to see that you found that this is a MS bug and not your own one. I hope they can fix it to help you.