# Slow editing in Visual Studio

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, aurelia

I have a project written in Aurelia and I am openning it with Visual Studio 2015 as a Web Site. The problem is when I try to edit a file it works very slow (I have to wait about 10 seconds before I can type).
I tried the next things, but it didn't work:

1. In tsconfig.json, set the compileOnSave to false
2. From VS => Tools => Options => Text Editor => TypeScript => Project =>  uncheck "Automatically compile TypeScript files which are not part of a project".

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What update version do you have for VS? (Help -> About) Mine was pretty slow with Typescript and VS Update 2.  Update 3 seems much faster.

Comment: I have Update 3

Comment: What version of typescript?  We downloaded a more recent version of Typescript from NPM rather than use the version built into VS.  (More recent at the time-- 1.8.x.)  You may also get a better answer faster if you add your ts.config file.  What version of .NET are you using?  4.6, Core, etc.

Comment: I have Typescript version 2.0.2, also installed from NPM. This project was not created with Visual Studio so I don't think that it is using a .Net Version.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553560/visual-studio-2015-is-very-slow

Comment: I gave up on VS for front-end development. It has continuous problems with node_modules folders. I use VS Code.