# Visual Studio 2015 running extremely slow

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

My computer specification:

[image].

I want to create an Android app for my 3rd year BscIT final project.
Android Studio is too heavy for my low spec computer. Now Visual Studio 2015 is also lagging too much with (not responding) message.

What should I do to have a smooth work as per my computers capacity?

Comment: Set the virtual memory as maximum as you can. And clean(remove) unnecessary programs which occupy memory. Turn off all the unnecessary functions in Tool- Options through searching on internet. Allow devenv.exe by your vaccine software. You can find useful advices on internet even in this StackOverflow.

Comment: Allow devenv.exe by your vaccine software (what does this mean ?)

Comment: There's an answer regarding devenv.exe in the stackoverflow question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553560/visual-studio-2015-is-very-slow

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but when i downloaded the latest version everything went fine and smooth. Download latest android studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Happie Coding..!!

Comment: iam asking of visual studio 2015